# cannot find .less modules in a tsx file in Next.js version 9.1.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using Next.js version 9.1.1 with Typescript and @zeit/next-less. Every time I import a less file in a tsx file this error is shown.

[image]

This error does not cause any problem with my builds. Styles are properly imported in development as well as in production.

How should I resolve this error? How should I tell Typescript to import .less files?
I have used externals.d.ts file but that doesn't seem to work.
My tsconfig.json file looks something like this -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx"],
  "include": ["externals.d.ts", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

My externals.d.ts file looks like this -

```
declare module '*.less' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```